# Xamarin UI Test on Local Android device not launching app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I’m struggling to get my UI Testing working on Android locally.

I’m using the APK which was archived as a release build with no shared runtimes and using the correct ABI apk in my build.

```
return ConfigureApp.Android
                    .EnableLocalScreenshots()
                    .PreferIdeSettings()
                    .ApkFile(ApkPath)
                    .StartApp(Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.DoNotClear);
```

I can see it connect to my physical phone device:

> 15-04-2019 10:28:57.423 +02:00 - 309 - QueryAdbDevices devices output:  [ "21f563e0550d7ece                device" ]
>   15-04-2019 10:28:57.454 +02:00 - 340 - QueryAdbDevices found attached devices:  [ "21f563e0550d7ece" ]
>   15-04-2019 10:28:57.467 +02:00 - 353 - Initializing Android app on device 21f563e0550d7ece with apk: ******
>   15-04-2019 10:28:57.809 +02:00 - 695 - Signing apk with Xamarin keystore.

I can see it deploy the app APK:

> -2019 10:28:59.805 +02:00 - 2691 - AdbArguments: '-s **** shell am instrument -e "target_package" "****" -e "debug" "false" -e "test_server_port" "50860" -e "class" "sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.InstrumentationBackend" ******test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner'.
>   15-04-2019 10:29:00.513 +02:00 - 3399 - Finished with exit code 0 in 703 ms.

I can also see it deploy the additional helper APKs:

> 15-04-2019 10:29:00.518 +02:00 - 3403 - launchable activity set as 
>   15-04-2019 10:29:00.521 +02:00 - 3407 - AdbArguments: '-s ***** forward tcp:50860 tcp:50860'.
>   15-04-2019 10:29:00.567 +02:00 - 3453 - Finished with exit code 0 in 40 ms.
>   15-04-2019 10:29:00.572 +02:00 - 3458 - Forwarded port 50860.

And then after this it just tries to ping the application, which then doesn’t launch on the device:

> 15-04-2019 10:29:00.656 +02:00 - 3542 - HTTP POST { Url: { AbsolutePath: "/ping", AbsoluteUri: "http://127.0.0.1:50860/ping", LocalPath: "/ping", Authority: "127.0.0.1:50860", HostNameType: IPv4, IsDefaultPort: False, IsFile: False, IsLoopback: True, PathAndQuery: "/ping", Segments: [ "/", "ping" ], IsUnc: False, Host: "127.0.0.1", Port: 50860, Query: "", Fragment: "", Scheme: "http", OriginalString: "http://127.0.0.1:50860/ping", DnsSafeHost: "127.0.0.1", IdnHost: "127.0.0.1", IsAbsoluteUri: True, UserEscaped: False, UserInfo: "" } }
>
> 15-04-2019 10:29:00.917 +02:00 - 3803 - HTTP POST { Url: { AbsolutePath: "/ping", AbsoluteUri: "http://127.0.0.1:50860/ping", LocalPath: "/ping", Authority: "127.0.0.1:50860", HostNameType: IPv4, IsDefaultPort: False, IsFile: False, IsLoopback: True, PathAndQuery: "/ping", Segments: [ "/", "ping" ], IsUnc: False, Host: "127.0.0.1", Port: 50860, Query: "", Fragment: "", Scheme: "http", OriginalString: "http://127.0.0.1:50860/ping", DnsSafeHost: "127.0.0.1", IdnHost: "127.0.0.1", IsAbsoluteUri: True, UserEscaped: False, UserInfo: "" } }

I'm using the following versions:

Android test running Xamarin.UITest version: 2.2.7

NUnit v2.6.4

NUnit adaptor v2.1.1

Visual Studio 2019 v15.9.11

Comment: Did you try to uninstall the app first over the adb shell? Note: the app needs to have the same signature "ConfigureApp.Android.Keystore(path, spass, kpass, alias).StartApp();"